# Unable to fix Django-Angular crud function

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs

I am trying to implement the crud functionality in django-angular
This is the Task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client_name = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField('date added', auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.task_name
```

This is the view I added:

```
class MyCRUDView(NgCRUDView):
    model_class = Task
```

This is the html file:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table class="table">
{% verbatim %}
    <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
        <td>{{ task.pk }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.task_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.client_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.date }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.status"></td>
    </tr>
{% endverbatim %}
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the js file for Angular:

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);

myServices.factory('Task', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('crud/task', {'pk': '@pk'},{})
}]);

var my_app = angular.module('myApp', [/* other dependencies */,'ngCookies']).run(function($http, $cookies) {
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
        //Add the following two lines
        $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    });

my_app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','Task', function ($scope, Task) {
    //Query returns an array of objects, Task.objects.all() by default
    $scope.models = Task.query();


}]);
```

The Angular script keeps giving me an error saying TaskProvider is not recognised. For the life of me I cannot understand where I am doing wrong. The code is almost a copy of the example code in the documentation for django-angular given here
http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic-crud-operations.html

Answer (score 1):

The Task factory is on the `myServices` module; but it should be on `myApp`. Assuming there are no other errors, this should get around the `TaskProvider` not recognized problem...

```
var my_app = angular.module('myApp', [/* other dependencies */, 
                  'ngResource','ngCookies']).run(function($http, $cookies) {
        $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
        //Add the following two lines
        $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    });

my_app.factory('Task', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('crud/task', {'pk': '@pk'},{})
}]);

my_app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','Task', function ($scope, Task) {
    //Query returns an array of objects, Task.objects.all() by default
    $scope.models = Task.query();


}]);
```

`myServices` isn't needed here (just make sure you add the `ngResource` dependency to `myApp`).

Comment: Some of it seems to work, I've got a new error that says, expected response to contain an array but got an object. It seems the resposnse is actually the whole html file rather than the single Task object  
Can you explain what the 'crud/task' does?